# how to call a written function in .aspx page from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

i have an asp:DropDownList and i want to disable it in some condition.it can happen with a function in aspx page.but from code behind (after some c# work) it wont!

this is the element:

Comment: Are you talking about cmbState.Enabled = false; ?

Comment: this is the element: 
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="cmbState" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="30px" Font-Size="Small"
                                Font-Bold="true" DataValueField="StateID" DataTextField="Name">
                            </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Can you please provide code here?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do? From my understanding, you want to disable the DropDownList if a certain condition is met. Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly i want to disable it but it wont get done from code behind

Comment: how can i write my function in aspx page and call it from code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="cmbState" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="30px" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true" DataValueField="StateID" DataTextField="Name" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
bool condition = true;
if (condition == true)
{
    cmbState.Enabled = false;
}
```

This should work unless you have something in your `Page_Load` method which would counter it.
The `AutoPostBack` property is important due to the order in which events are carried out on the page.